# JSON Parsing impossible, but JSON Lint says it's ok

Tags: jquery, json

I am using jquery to receive a few lines of javascript and get this err

Unexpected token ILLEGA

This is the complete json I am trying to parse. JSON Lint does not complain...

```
{
    "executionResult": "",
     "outputText": "",
     "stacktraceText": "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: asfdsf for class: Script1\n at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)\n  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)\n  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)\n  at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.bufferAndPostProcess(ContentBufferingFilter.java:169)\n at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:126)\n at org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java:163)\n   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)\n  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)\n  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:366)\n   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)\n at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)\n    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)\n   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)\n    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)\n   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)\n    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)\n   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)\n  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)\n   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)\n    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)\n   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)\n  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)\n   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)\n    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)\n   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)\n at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)\n   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)\n   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)\n   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)\n    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)\n   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)\n   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)\n   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:167)\n  at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)\n    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)\n  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)\n  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)\n  at de.hybris.platform.util.RootRequestFilter.doFilter(RootRequestFilter.java:883)\n at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)\n  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)\n  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)\n    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)\n    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)\n  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)\n  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)\n  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:554)\n  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)\n    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)\n at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)\n   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:396)\n"
}
```

Comment: How are you receiving/using it?

Comment: Maybe you should show us your JSON bit.

Comment: You are trying to parse an exception?

Comment: @Lazarus: If you edit questions please ensure not to break hthem. You removed characters (e.g. the starting `{`) from his JSON.

Comment: You may want to put the raw json file up on a server.  As this is parse related, any extra formatting causes too many variances.  My first blush guess would be that you've got newline characters in the literal itself, but that's because of the formatting I'm seeing here.

Comment: Is it possible that you've set up a jQuery "$.getJSON()" call, and that you're trying to pass the value it gives your "success" handler to a JSON parser?  If so, then perhaps the problem is that you're trying to parse a JavaScript object that's *already* been parsed for you from the raw string sent by the server.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Could be worse, you could make the output 100s of columns wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is fine, so apparently what you're asking jQuery to parse *isn't* quite what you've quoted, as jQuery is [happy to parse it](http://jsbin.com/ituwe4). In that example I'm loading the JSON text via ajax.

If you're reading the JSON text from a JavaScript *string* rather than by loading it from somewhere, e.g.:

```
var str = '{ ' +
          '"executionResult": "",' +
          '"outputText": "",' +
          '"stacktraceText": "..."' +
          '}';
```

...then quote the actual string literal you're trying to parse, and we can tell you what's wrong with it. But that JSON is fine.

Comment: There was a \a character somewhere in that string, which caused the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The string value inside the quotes assigned to `stacktraceText` is the problem. JK's comment hit the nail on the head.

You are clearly trying to deal with an error message (exception) received somewhere that is not intended to be parsed in the way you are doing it.

If you have control of the error message make it make sense in the context of a value pair which is normally expected for JSON.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the string?  It looks like a perfectly good string constant to me.

Comment: @Pointy I think you raise a valid point both above and here. FYI I've had problems with colons in used in strings sent over from the server before in JSON context. Don't ask me why though, I just restructured the server side encoding to give me value pairs properly and that solved it.